# Ts-node : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I was trying to use the top level in the project and saw that it was necessary to change the module from tscofnig to esnext or system, but for some reason my ts-node's error.
And I already put the type: module I tried to use the flag: --experimental-modules but the error still does not know how to solve.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "micro-hr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files --no-copy-ignored",
    "start:dev": "ts-node-dev --experimental-modules --inspect --respawn --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts",
    "start:debug": "node start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint --fix",
    "lint2": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:generate": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.4",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^9.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^9.1.2",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/helmet": "^0.0.48",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.4",
    "@types/pino": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/pino-http": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.1",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.8.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "pino-pretty": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.62",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tscpaths": "^0.0.9",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "amqplib": "^0.6.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "envalid": "^6.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "extendable-error": "^0.1.7",
    "helmet": "^4.1.0",
    "nabbitmq": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.3",
    "pino": "^6.5.1",
    "pino-http": "^5.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "spt-rabbit-helpers": "^1.0.6",
    "tsyringe": "^4.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.25"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "__tests__"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

main:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import express from 'express';
import { RabbitServer } from 'spt-rabbit-helpers';
import validateEnv from 'utils/validateEnvs';
import {
  RabbitMqConnectionFactory,
  ConsumerFactory,
  PublisherFactory,
  RabbitMqConnection,
} from 'nabbitmq';
import { container, singleton } from 'tsyringe';

const factory = new RabbitMqConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri('amqp://localhost:5672');
const ConsumerConnection = await factory.newConnection();
const PublisherConnection = await factory.newConnection();
container.registerInstance('Consumer_Connection', ConsumerConnection);
container.registerInstance('Publisher_Connection', PublisherConnection);
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Why does it take a masters degree in javasript to use top level await?

Answer (score 35):

After a lot of searching, I found this solution works perfect:

https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/922#issuecomment-673155000

Just add a `"ts-node"` block to your `tsconfig.json` file as below:

> ```
> {
>   "ts-node": {
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       "module": "commonjs"
>     }
>   },
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "module": "esnext"
>   }
> }
> ```

And it has been documented in the ts-node official page "[Via tsconfig.json](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#via-tsconfigjson-recommended)" part.

This saved hours of my life.

Comment: easiest answer for me :)
thanks

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. This issue happens to me every so often and it's so frustrating to fix, especially when it's a small little script and you just want to get it running.

Answer (score 31):

To run ts-node (or plain node for that matter) you need to use `"module": "commonjs", "target": "ES2017"`, otherwise the `import`/`export` statements are illegally placed in an IIFE.

So I would suggest using another file called *node.tsconfig.json* with the following contents:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017" // For NodeJS 8 compat, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target for more info
    }
}
```

And then run ts-node with `--project ./node.tsconfig.json`

Comment: It should be noted that the project arg in the ts-node command MUST COME BEFORE the script name. e.g. `ts-node --project ./node.tsconfig.json your-script.ts`

Comment: Apparently ts-node also accepts format 

`{"ts-node": {"compilerOptions": { ... } } }`

...in the main `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I couldn't get this answer or the comments to work, even though they looked promising.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, Try Looking at the configuration outputted by `ts-node --showConfig`, maybe ts-node isn’t loading your configuration.

Comment: Thanks. `yarn ts-node  --project ./tsconfig.node.json --showConfig` is a good command to know about, but I'm still not sure how to get your answer to work, given that the showConfig seems to say that it's loading my extended config properly.

Comment: I think I was able to solve my problem after reading https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module. I added this to my tsconfig.json: `"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "ES2017"
    }
  },`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by changing the `module` in `tsconfig.json` to `commonjs` and removing the `module` key in `package.json`:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
    "module": "CommonJS",
}
```

Comment: This removes the ability to use top level await, which the OP is trying to accomplish

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `React`, "commonjs" can not be set for TypeScript.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext"
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "tsnode": "node --loader ts-node/esm --no-warnings"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
    }
}
```

**hello.ts**

```
import * as os from "os"
console.log("os", os);
```

Two ways to execute the TypeScript file:

- `node --loader ts-node/esm --no-warnings hello.ts`
- `npm run tsnode hello.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), instead use [vite-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-node):

```
npx vite-node script.ts
```

Job done, no messing around! No config changes needed!

(It even lets you access node 'fs').

NB: [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) also works.