# Import TypeScript module without NPM 'build' script

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I need to import a package that has this configuration:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects",
  "main": "src/index.ts"
}
```

I'm importing this package from an outer package via:

my-outer-package/src/index.ts

```js
import {Language} from 'com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects';
```

Is it possible to keep my dependency configuration above as is and run `ts-node src/index.ts`? I've a project similiarly structured that runs fine in `ts-node`. Somehow my current project fails with this:

```bash
> ts-node src/index.ts # my-outer-package
< my-outer-package\node_modules\com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects\src\index.ts:1
import Language, {Direction} from './language';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Also note that running `ts-node com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects/src/index.ts` doesn't produce this module-related error.

Here are the full sources:

- [language-objects](https://github.com/matheusdiasdesouzads/language-objects-js)
- [message-locator](https://github.com/matheusdiasdesouzads/message-locator-js) (imports language-objects from NPM registry)

I tried everything in this question: [Ts-node : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63870080)

- Set `compilerOptions.module` to `"CommonJS"`.
- Set `compilerOptions.target` to `"ES2017"`.
- Set `compilerOptions.esModuleInterop` to `true`.
- Set `type` to `"module"` in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug probably on ts-node. When the dependency is on the file system, that is, when I replace:

```
"com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects": "^1.1.0"
```

by:

```
"com.matheusdiasdesouzads.js.language-objects": "file:../language-objects-js"
```

My code compiles successfully (it creates a shortcut). I've commited an issue on [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1873).